# Controlling memory spikes when loading local (Office and iWork) files in UIWebView

Tags: ios, memory-management, ios4, uiwebview

I am using UIWebView to open local files of Office (ppt, xls, doc) and iWork (numbers, pages, key) formats, all less than 5 MB in size. To load them, I simply do:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];      
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

When loading some of these files in web view (especially ppts with large number of images in them), the memory usage shoots up to almost 35 MB causing my app to crash. I have looked around various iOS forums but haven't really found a solution. Does using loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL: help in keeping the memory footprint down or are there any other tricks to using UIWebView?

Comment: Are you viewing the files inside the webview or are you using webview to just download the files so the right app opens the file ?

Comment: I was only loading the file with the code shown above. Anyways, this was pre iOS5, will have to verify if they have made any performance improvements to UIWebView. I am not working on this project anymore by the way.

Comment: @Sushant 35MB will always be a problem at least for the next 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be the case for a crash. An app using 35MB of RAM is not too much. I suggest you run the static analyzer for leaks. Also, what type of crash do you get? Do you see memory warnings being issued just before it crashes?

Comment: An app using 35MB of RAM is not too much. Are you kidding? The OS starts throwing memory warnings at 14-15MB. Consider the dozens of other apps that are running in the background and the RAM dedicated to the OS itself and you will understand why 14-15MB is the safe memory threshold.